# Wix. Basic fetch call to retrieve data on page

Tags: json, fetch, velo

I canot for the life of me figure out how to make a call to a url, and phrase the json and display it on the page in lets say $w("#Element").

So basically what Im doing on the backend in service.jws

```
import {fetch} from 'wix-fetch';

// ...

export function  getdata(){

fetch('http://tcokchallenge.com/admin_cp/test3.json', {method: 'get'})
  .then( (httpResponse) => {
    if (httpResponse.ok) {
      return httpResponse.json();
    } else {
      return Promise.reject("Fetch did not succeed");
    }
  } )
  .then(json => console.log(json.glossary["title"]))
  .catch(err => console.log(err));
  }
```

On the frontend, Its sloppy, but this is where Im stuck.

```
import {getdata} from 'backend/service.jsw';

$w.onReady(function () {
console.log('ready');
$w("#Element").glossary.title.getdata();
})
```

In the JSON file

```
{
    "glossary": {
        "title": "example glossary",
        "GlossDiv": {
            "title": "S",
            "GlossList": {
                "GlossEntry": {
                    "ID": "SGML",
                    "SortAs": "SGML",
                    "GlossTerm": "Standard Generalized Markup Language",
                    "Acronym": "SGML",
                    "Abbrev": "ISO 8879:1986",
                    "GlossDef": {
                        "para": "A meta-markup language, used to create markup languages such as DocBook.",
                        "GlossSeeAlso": ["GML", "XML"]
                    },
                    "GlossSee": "markup"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues with your code:

1. You don't return the Promise from the backend function.
2. If you would return it, you would be returning the return value of the console.log() function, which is not what you want.
3. On the frontend, you're not calling the backend function properly.
4. Also, you're not setting the element's value properly.

Your backend code should look something like this:

```
import {fetch} from 'wix-fetch';

export function  getdata(){
  return fetch('http://tcokchallenge.com/admin_cp/test3.json', {method: 'get'})
    .then( (httpResponse) => {
      if (httpResponse.ok) {
        return httpResponse.json();
      } else {
        return Promise.reject("Fetch did not succeed");
      }
    } );
}
```

Notice the `return` before the fetch and the removal of the console.log.

Your frontend code, should look something like this:

```
import {getdata} from 'backend/service.jsw';

$w.onReady(function () {
  getdata()
    .then( (json) => {
      $w("#Element").value = json.glossary.title;
    } )
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
    } );
} );
```

Notice that `getdata()` returns a Promise, so you need to use `.then()` (or `async`/`await`). Also, you don't say what type of element `Element` is. So I can't say for sure what property you use to set it's value. The most likely candidates are `.value` (used for input elements) or `.text` (used for text elements and text boxes).